# ajax selecting specific part of a HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

I am trying to AJAX load a chained dropdown list using django, where the dropdown choices are based on the choice of another field... I have more than one element which needs to be chained, So I tried to chain multiple Ajax requests one after the other which I wasnt able to ... Now I am trying to to bring in the ajax response of different choice fields in single html and render the ajax response based on the id of the div's... Can you please let me know if I can explicitly specify the part of the data(div) that can be replaced... Thanks!

**AJAX PART**

**store_dropdown_list_options.html:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for store in stores %}
    <option value="{{ store.id }}">{{ store.StoreNM }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**views:**

```
def load_store(request):
    ReadingAreaNo_id = request.GET.get('ReadingArea')
    print('value is ', ReadingAreaNo_id)
    stores = StoreMaster.objects.filter(ReadingAreaNo_id=ReadingAreaNo_id).order_by('StoreNO')
    print('stores are ', stores)
    return render(request, 'rateshare/store_dropdown_list_options.html', {'stores': stores})
```

**URLS:**

```
path('ajax/load-stores/', views.load_store, name='ajax_load_stores'),
```

**script:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#id_ReadingAreaNo").change(function () {
    var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");   
    var ReadingAreaNo = $(this).val();      
        $.ajax({                       
            url: url,                    
            data: {
                'ReadingArea': ReadingAreaNo       
            },
            success: function (data) {   
                $("#id_StoreNO").html(data);  
                
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

There will be different div's rendered in the ajax html and so I am looking to replace only a  specific part of the html on the success of ajax request...

**EDIT 1: console printed the data and the typeof data**

> //type
>
> string
>
> //data

```
> 
> (index):311
> <option value="">---------</option>
> 
> <option value="1">Sangeeth &amp; CO</option>
> 
> <option value="2">ASTY Shizuoka</option>
```

Comment: Hi , so your ajax response there will be many div you only need to get div html of specified div ?

Comment: Yes Swati. figured out a solution which works, but I am not sure about the efficiency or the reliability . will add it as an answer and if you have any other approach please let know...

Comment: Hi, instead of split you can use `.siblings()` as you have html string return so that should work . i.e: `$(data).siblings("yourdivid").html()`

Comment: will try that !! thanks much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split each **DIV's** in the HTML with a character (* here) and then used the JavaScript split() to split the div's of the ajax response based on the splitting character. Then passed the required div as ajax response based on the index after the split...

AJAX PART

**store_dropdown_list_options.html:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for store in stores %}
    <option value="{{ store.id }}">{{ store.StoreNM }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</div>*
<div id="div2">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for meter in meters %}
    <option value="{{ meter.id }}">{{ meter.MeterNo }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#id_ReadingAreaNo").change(function () {
    var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");  
    var ReadingAreaNo = $(this).val();  
    var MeterKBN = $("#id_MeterKBN").val()
    
        $.ajax({                       
            url: url,                    
            data: {
                'ReadingArea': ReadingAreaNo ,       
                'MeterKBN' : MeterKBN
            },
            success: function (data) {   
                var test1 = data.split('*');
                $("#id_StoreNO").html(test1[0]);  
                $("#id_MeterID").html(test1[1]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("#id_ReadingAreaNo").change(function () {
        //pass div id as a parameter
        dynamicAjax("id_StoreNO");
    });

//Use that parameter to replace the HTML value based on ajax
function dynamicAjax(storeId){
    var url = $("#personForm").attr("data-cities-url");   
    var ReadingAreaNo = $(this).val();      
        $.ajax({                       
            url: url,                    
            data: {
                'ReadingArea': ReadingAreaNo       
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                //dynamic HTML replacement based on the id  
                $("#"+storeId).html(data);  
                
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Madhu... I believe this dynamically inserts the data. What I am looking for is that , just like how you have inserted the data to the store id, I want a certain div in that ajax response (data) to be passed into the store id...